# Installation Babun failed - create empty .babun folder

Tags: installation, babun

I´m trying to install [babun](http://babun.github.io/) on Windows 10.

When I run `babun-master\babun-dist\install\install.bat` I got this message :

```
[babun] Installing babun
[babun] ERROR: Erro de entrada: Não é possível encontrar o arquivo de script "C:\path\babun-master\babun-dist\install\dist\freespace.vbs".
[babun] ERROR: Unable to run .vbs script to determine free space on drive.
[babun] ERROR: This is often caused by anti-virus applications blocking execution of .vbs files.
[babun] ERROR: If you are sure that you have enough disk space, you can continue at your own risk.
[babun] Do you want to continue? [S,N]?
```

If I disable or enable my firewall, I have the same result :

1. The terminal closes
2. The folder `.babun` is created but empty

Someone knows what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
- Even if you can answer by Y/N to install it. If your firewall is active, the installation will just make a `.babun` folder empty and stop.

> So disable your firewall and restart the installation.